# Highcharts many panes

Tags: highcharts

I took [this](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/candlestick-and-volume/) example from Highcharts 
and tried to add the 3rd pane, same as the 2nd one. I added 3rd element to `yAxis` (same as the 2nd one) and to `series` (with `name = Volume1` and `yAxis = 2`)

```
yAxis: [{
        labels: {
            align: 'right',
            x: -3
        },
        title: {
            text: 'OHLC'
        },
        height: '60%',
        lineWidth: 2,
        resize: {
            enabled: true
        }
    }, {
        labels: {
            align: 'right',
            x: -3
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Volume'
        },
        top: '65%',
        height: '35%',
        offset: 0,
        lineWidth: 2
    }, {
        labels: {
            align: 'right',
            x: -3
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Volume2'
        },
        top: '65%',
        height: '35%',
        offset: 0,
        lineWidth: 2
    }],

series: [{
        type: 'candlestick',
        name: 'AAPL',
        data: ohlc,
        dataGrouping: {
            units: groupingUnits
        }
    }, {
        type: 'column',
        name: 'Volume',
        data: volume,
        yAxis: 1,
        dataGrouping: {
            units: groupingUnits
        }
    }, {
        type: 'column',
        name: 'Volume1',
        data: volume,
        yAxis: 2,
        dataGrouping: {
            units: groupingUnits
        }
    }]
```

but I got 2 charts in the 2nd pane instead.
Please take a look at [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2Lkg06g1/)

I don't care which chart type to use, I just need more panes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The controlling factor is `top` and `height` in the `yAxis` settings.

If you change the yAxis to have the following, it will work as you intend.

```
yAxis: [
  {
    height: '60%',
    ...
  }, {
    top: '65%',
    height: '15%',
    ...
  }, {
    top: '80%',
    height: '15%',
    ...
  }]
```

You can of course play with the settings to create exactly the dimensions you seek.

**Working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/2Lkg06g1/2/

**API on yAxis.height:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/yAxis.height

**API on yAxis.top:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/yAxis.top